# remove www from https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, url-rewriting

I'm trying to find a htaccess rewrite to remove www. from https: pages only. Every article I've found removes www for all pages.

What do I need in .htaccess to do this?

https://www.mydomain.com should be https://mydomain.com

https://mydomain.com should remain https://mydomain.com

http://www.mydomain.com should remain http://www.mydomain.com

http://mydomain.com should remain http://mydomain.com

I've been able to get the following working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(https?://)www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R,QSA]
```

But this rewrites both https and http

Here is my current .htaccess

```
SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 5

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1

# You may need to uncomment the following line on some hosting environments, 
# for example on unitedhosting.co.uk
# RewriteBase /


# The following line has been added in order to exclude the webim
# directory from the LemonStand URL processing.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webim



#
# Do not allow executing any PHP scripts
#

RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ index.php [L]

#
# The following section automatically adds a trailing slash to all URLs
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^HEAD$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$ 
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# The following line has been added in order to exclude the webim
# directory from the LemonStand URL processing.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webim


#
# Product files downloading URL
#

RewriteRule (^download_product_file/.*) index.php?q=/$1 [L,QSA]

# The following line has been added in order to exclude the webim
# directory from the LemonStand URL processing.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webim


#
# Administration Area file downloading URL
#

RewriteRule ls_backend/files/get/(.*) index.php?q=/backend_file_get/$1 [L]

# The following line has been added in order to exclude the webim
# directory from the LemonStand URL processing.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webim


#
# All other requests
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.(ico|js|jpg|gif|css|png|swf|flv|txt|xml|xls|pdf|eot|woff|ttf|svg|mp4)$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(phproad/thirdpart/.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 "File not found"

#
# PHP configuration
#

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 31536000
php_flag session.use_cookies on
php_flag session.use_only_cookies on
php_value session.name FWCSESSID

php_flag short_open_tag on
php_flag asp_tags on

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_value date.timezone GMT

php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M

php_value memory_limit 264M
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check that you're on port 443 and the hostname starts with www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.

# Redirect to domain without the www
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: Server port can be non-standard (happens when more than one SSL certificate needs to be served on the same IP). In this case %{SERVER_PORT} can have value different to standard 443 :/

Comment: @dardub I had an error which I corrected probably as you were testing.

Comment: @dardub: What do you mean by "everything"? Show us the URL that needs to be redirected; show how is WAS redirected and how it SHOULD be redirected. Otherwise your comment has no value and is not helping in any way.

Comment: well now with the new code, nothing happens.
but before, if I typed http:// www.mydomain.com it sent me to https:// mydomain.com

Comment: i appreciate your help, sorry I've just been at this for over an hour with no luck

Comment: @dardub If you still aren't getting the result you want with either my answer or @Floern's, something is definitely wrong elsewhere in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

If `HTTPS` is `on` and `HTTP_HOST` is `www.mydomain.com`, then it redirects to `https://mydomain.com/`.

Comment: Maybe something else in my .htaccess is screwing it up. But that doesn't work for me either. If I type https:// www.mydomain.com I still get https:// www.mydomain.com

Comment: and I did remember to change the mydomain.com part in your solution :D

Comment: ok, I edited a little bit, but actually I guess it doesn't change the situation.

Comment: @dardub: try moving these rules to the top of .htaccess ... otherwise -- show your whole .htaccess here. This rule should work just fine.

Comment: I added my .htaccess to my post. I placed Floern's solution at the top of .htaccess and it does not rewrite anything.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this via apache virtualhost

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 Redirect / https://example.com/
 </VirtualHost>

<virtualHost *:443>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
 ServerName example.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition (to your existing redirect rule):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove `www.` from both `https` and `http`, and without having to add your domain.

```
# remove www. (generic method with HTTPS support)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Meu arquivo final .htaccess sendo usado dentro de uma pasta e com redirecionamento de https também.

My finishing file .htaccess inner using path url (ex: example.com/intranet):

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
DefaultLanguage pt-BR
ServerSignature Off
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# Check that you're on port 443 and the hostname starts with www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.

# Redirect to domain without the www
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/intranet/$1 [L,R,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```